# How to search for a string in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like the below:

```
pb_file = [ 
    ['n012345_y','n012345_e','n023561234_u','n012345_p','n012345_k']
    ['n124536_i','n1542453_m','n10978_k','n124536_m'] 
]
```

The search string is

```
search_string = 'n012345_'
```

and I want to search for items in `pb_file` that contain the string 'n012345_'(`search_string`). How can I get all items that contain 'n012345_' ?

The output should be like this…

```
output_list = ['n012345_y','n012345_e','n012345_p','n012345_k']
```

Here is my code:

```
pb_file = [ ['n012345_y','n012345_e','n023561234_u','n012345_p','n012345_k'], 
              ['n124536_i','n1542453_m','n10978_k','n124536_m'] ]

search_string = 'n012345_' 
output_list = search_string in [j for i in pb_file for j in i]

print (output_list)
```

But, it displays True or False. I want a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
output_list = [item for items in pb_file for item in items if search_string in item]
```

To break down how this works:

```
output_list = [
    item                                     # the thing that will be in the output list
    for items in pb_file for item in items   # nested loop for item in each sublist
    if search_string in item                 # item only included if this is true
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import functools
search_string = 'n012345_'
pb_file = [ ['n012345_y','n012345_e','n023561234_u','n012345_p','n012345_k'], 
              ['n124536_i','n1542453_m','n10978_k','n124536_m'] ]
def callback(acc, arr):
  for item in arr:
    if search_string in item:
      acc.append(item)
  return acc

functools.reduce(callback, pb_file, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pb_file = [ ['n012345_y','n012345_e','n023561234_u','n012345_p','n012345_k'],['n124536_i','n1542453_m','n10978_k','n124536_m'] ]

output = [entry for main_list in pb_file for entry in main_list if "n012345_" in entry]
```

Output:

`['n012345_y', 'n012345_e', 'n012345_p', 'n012345_k']`

Loop through the list and check for substring or equality in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following:

```
output_list = [entry for data in pb_file for entry in data if entry.startswith(search_string)]
```